# create a text file using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I need to create a text file  bank_account,bank_amount etc. as a list that details i put on the string variable but here only create one record not create the all of record.

```
function bank_details(values){
    var bank_account=0;
    var bank_amount=0;
    var first_name="";
    var id="";
    var string="";
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) 
    { 

            bank_amount = values[j][0] ? values[j][0] : 0;
            bank_account = values[j][1] ? values[j][1] : 0;
            id=values[j][2] ? values[j][2] : 0;
            alert(bank_amount);
            string =" a ="+bank_amount+" "+bank_account+" "+id;
            rbf_getRelatedIds2("R2846945","Emp_Bank_Tran", id, get_rel_id);

            download(string, 'myfilename.txt', 'text/plain');
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the string (Using `+=`), and use `download()` at the very end:

```
function bank_details(values) {
    var bank_account=0;
    var bank_amount=0;
    var first_name="";
    var id="";
    var string="";
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        bank_amount = values[j][0] ? values[j][0] : 0;
        bank_account = values[j][1] ? values[j][1] : 0;
        id=values[j][2] ? values[j][2] : 0;
        alert(bank_amount);
        string += " a ="+bank_amount+" "+bank_account+" "+id;
        rbf_getRelatedIds2("R2846945","Emp_Bank_Tran", id, get_rel_id);
    }

    download(string, 'myfilename.txt', 'text/plain');
}
```

Additionally, you may want to add a new line (`+ "\n"`) at the end of the `string += ...` to put each entry on a new line.

Comment: Also, not sure what `rbf_getRelatedIds2` does, but that apparently doesn't do anything in this case. You can likely remove it.

Comment: thank you, it work but i need it as list it print in the one row

Comment: Read the last line in my answer @SampathPathirana